# Tracking Clicks [Outbound Links] with Autotrack.js

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to find a clear method of tracking clicks to external sites from a site I have built, it appears a lot of information available on this is contradictory or incomplete. I have found autotrack.js on Github which looks like a simpler method, so my question is three-fold, I'll make the question super clear so there is a super clear answer for others in the same conundrum as me.

1. What snippet/script is added to the HTML and where? I currently have the standard GA snippet for tracking page loads before the `</body>` tag.
2. Should I amend / edit the `<a>` tags to make sense of the who clicked what? I.e. name them, can this be avoided or automated, what I mean is there a script smart enough to name it the same as the destination, like reallygoodlist.com or fb.com/reallygoodlist ?
3. Is there any GA work required? Set up Goals etc, ideally I would be looking to avoid this - I have a lot of links.

Here is my site (if it helps):
http://www.reallygoodlist.com

Comment: Autotrack comes with a lot of documentation for autotrack.js in general (https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack#installation-and-usage) and the outbound link tracker specifically (https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/plugins/outbound-link-tracker.md). I doubt that any answer on SO could be more clear, or at least it would help if you read it and come back with any specific problem you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) What snippet/script is added to the HTML and where? I currently have the standard GA snippet for tracking page loads before the  tag.

The [installation and usage](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack#installation-and-usage) section of the autotrack documentation shows how to install autotrack, so I'll just link to it rather than repeating.

If you're just using the default GA tag, you can probably copy/paste most of the code there, changing the parts relevant to you: e.g. if you only care about outbound link tracking, then only include the `outboundLinkTracker` plugin.

It also looks like you're installing code via `npm`, so in this case you can link autotrack's source file in the `node_modules` directory as you've done with the Babel polyfill.

```
<script src="node_modules/autotrack/autotrack.js"></script>
```

> 2) Should I amend / edit the  tags to make sense of the who clicked what ? i.e. name them, can this be avoided or automated, what i mean is ether a script smart enough to name it the same as the destination, like reallygoodlist.com or fb.com/reallygoodlist ?

Autotrack's `outboundLinkTracker` plugin automatically sets the link's URL as the event label, so you probably don't need to do anything unless that's not enough.

If you want more control than that, setting one of the [common options](https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack/blob/master/docs/common-options.md) will allow you to custom any data that is sent to GA.

> 3) Is there any GA work required? Set up Goals etc, ideally I would be looking to avoid this - I have a lot of links.

Not for outbound link tracking. It's just tracking the data as events, so you'll be able to find them in your event reports in GA.

Comment: thank you Philip, just needed a little clarity as there is a lot of incomplete information out there.

Comment: https://measureschool.com/video/google-analytics-autotrack-js-explained/

I have included this for clarity on the problem that us who are unfamiliar with auto track are facing - this video explains its installation and does not reflect the instructions provided here. Also worth asking - is there a verification process where GA can detect if we have installed correctly ?

Comment: Always refer to the official documentation, as it's the best source of truth. As for how to debug/verify your implementation, the [Debugging](https://devsite.googleplex.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging) guide in the anaytics developers site should be helpful.